# Select and Case statements using BASH

Tags: bash, select, case

The idea behind this code is to print options to the user and allow them to execute commands. The file name is `example.sh`. I simply run it by `./example.sh` and it gives 3 options: author, type, exit.

```
NAME="Mark Zuck"

PS3="enter command: "

select var in author type exit
do
    case $var in           
        author)          
            echo $NAME   
            ;;

        type)           
            cat $2     
            ;;



        exit)
            exit
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Whenever I type author, the output is Mark Zuck, but I am trying to execute the command "type".

After putting 2 <"file name">, it should give me the contents of the file.

cat $2 doesn't work. I don't know how to solve this issue.

```
1) author
2) type
3) exit
enter command: 2 file1
enter command:
```

The output is above.

It should give me the content of the "file1" (file1 does exist)

Comment: `select` doesn't support arguments, just selection from the numeric list. If you want to support arguments, you can't use `select` (probably `read` instead, though it'll be more complicated). Also `$2` refers to the second argument passed *to the script* (so if you ran `./example.sh firstarg secondarg`, `$2` would be "secondarg"). You didn't pass a second argument (or even a first), so `$2` is empty.

Comment: $1 doesn't work either, I am also required to use select statement. This is an assignment.

Comment: As I said, `select` doesn't support arguments, so you simply cannot use it the way you're trying to. I suggest asking your teacher for clarification or a hint.

Comment: With your example, when you type `1`, it takes the _author_ branch. When you type `2`, it takes the _type_ branch and executes the `cat`, which of course hangs forever, unless you had supplied suitable  arguments to your script. So your program behaves exactly as one would expect. It is not clear to me, what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

`select` returns two values:

1. The first is in your custom `var` and contains the token associated to the number in select list
2. The second is in `REPLY` (like built-in `read` command) and contains the number

Ok? it's the standard test case.
If you type another response on select prompt, `var` is nul (empty) and `REPLY` contains the response!

So, I think, this script is for you.

Of course, the coma (`,`) is not adapted for you, it's just an example. Use what you want.

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

NAME="Mark Zuck"

PS3="enter command: "

select var in author type exit
do
    case "$var,$REPLY" in
        "author,1")
            echo "$NAME"
        ;;
        ",2 "*)
            filename="${REPLY#2 }"
            echo "filename=<$filename>"
            cat "${filename}"
        ;;
        "exit,3")
            exit
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Test:

```
> bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.2.9(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

> ./test_select.sh 
1) author
2) type
3) exit
enter command: 1
Mark Zuck
enter command: 2 test_select.sh
filename=<test_select.sh>
#! /usr/bin/env bash

NAME="Mark Zuck"

PS3="enter command: "

select var in author type exit
do
    case "$var,$REPLY" in
        "author,1")
            echo "$NAME"
        ;;
        ",2 "*)
            filename="${REPLY#2 }"
            echo "filename=<$filename>"
            cat "${filename}"
        ;;
        "exit,3")
            exit
        ;;
    esac
done
enter command: 3

>
```

Comment: This code still doesnt work. What I want to achieve is that whenever I type "2 <filename> " it should cat the content of the file. With your code the output is like this;
1) author
2) type
3) exit
enter command: 1
Mark Zuck
enter command: 2 file1
enter command: ^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 ./example.sh

Comment: Works fine on my Linux with GNU bash, version 5.2.9(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)